# Is there a way to graphically develop UI using Tizen sdk?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am trying to develop an app on Tizen for a Gear s2.  I have had trouble developing UI aspects strictly in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UI Builder to develop Tizen mobile and wearable apps.

Open Tizen IDE

File > New >Tizen Native Project > UI Builder - Single View (Circle)

You will now be presented with a visual gui editor with different ui components.

Comment: "Gear Watch Designer" can be used, but only if app is a watchface. It is easy to use program, fully graphical. http://developer.samsung.com/gear/design/watch-designer